# FP - Condense and 'nice' code

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Writing code in F# in most cases results in very condense an intuitive work. This piece of code looks somehow imperative and inconvenient to me.

- `times` is an array of float values

Lines inside the file `times.csv` always look like that:

```
Mai 06 2011 05:43:45 nachm.,00:22.99
Mai 04 2011 08:59:12 nachm.,00:22.73
Mai 04 2011 08:58:27 nachm.,00:19.38
Mai 04 2011 08:57:54 nachm.,00:18.00
```

- `average` generates an average of the values, dropping the lowest and highest time
- `getAllSubsetsOfLengthN` creates a sequence of all consecutive subsets of length `n`. Is there a 'nicer' solution to that? Or does already exist something like that inside the F# core?
- `bestAverageOfN` finds the lowest average of all the subsets

---

```
let times =
    File.ReadAllLines "times.csv"
    |> Array.map (fun l -> float (l.Substring((l.LastIndexOf ':') + 1)))
let average set =
    (Array.sum set - Array.min set - Array.max set) / float (set.Length - 2)
let getAllSubsetsOfLengthN n (set:float list) =
    seq { for i in [0 .. set.Length - n] -> set
                                            |> Seq.skip i
                                            |> Seq.take n }
let bestAverageOfN n =
    times
    |> Array.toList
    |> getAllSubsetsOfLengthN n
    |> Seq.map (fun t -> t
                         |> Seq.toArray
                         |> average)
    |> Seq.min
```

What I am looking for are nicer, shorter or easier solutions. Every useful post will be upvoted, of course :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without much thinking, there are some basic functional refactorings you can make. For example, in the calculation of `bestAverageOfN`, you can use function composition:

```
let bestAverageOfN n =
    times
    |> Array.toList
    |> getAllSubsetsOfLengthN n
    |> Seq.map (Seq.toArray >> average)
    |> Seq.min
```

Other than this and the suggestion by desco, I don't think there is anything I would change. If you don't use your special `average` function anywhere in the code, you could write it inline as a lambda function, but that really depends on your personal preferences.

Just for the sake of generality, I would probably make `times` an argument of `bestAverageOfN`:

```
let bestAverageOfN n times =
    times
    |> Seq.windowed n
    |> Seq.map (fun set ->
           (Array.sum set - Array.min set - Array.max set) / float (set.Length - 2))
    |> Seq.min
```

Comment: That pretty much covers it all. Good to know about `Seq.windowed`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I guess, getAllSubsetsOfLengthN can be replaced with Seq.windowed

so bestAverageOfN will look like:

```
let bestAverageOfN n =
    times
    |> Seq.windowed n
    |> Seq.map average
    |> Seq.min
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned regex for parsing your input, I thought I'd show you such a solution. It may well be overkill, but it is also a more functional solution since regular expressions are declarative while substring stuff is more imperative. Regex is also nice since it is easier to grow if the structure of your input changes, index substring stuff can get messy, and I try to avoid it completely.

First a couple active patterns,

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions
let (|Groups|_|) pattern input =
    let m = Regex.Match(input, pattern)
    if m.Success then
        Some([for g in m.Groups -> g.Value] |> List.tail)
    else
        None

open System
let (|Float|_|) input =
    match Double.TryParse(input) with
    | true, value -> Some(value)
    | _ -> None
```

Adopting @ildjarn's `times` implementation:

```
let times =
    File.ReadAllLines "times.csv"
    |> Array.map (function Groups @",.*?:(.*)$" [Float(value)] -> value)
```

Comment: +1 That makes the parsing a lot more readable. Alternatively, you could also create some clever active pattern for picking a substring.

Comment: Despite your expression ignores the decimal character, it looks perfectly functional. Few more lines of code, though. I love this solution a lot and will probably learn a bit of active patterns :p Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since `bestAversageOfN` has already been covered, here's an alternative implementation of `times`:

```
let times =
    File.ReadAllLines "times.csv"
    |> Array.map (fun l -> l.LastIndexOf ':' |> (+) 1 |> l.Substring |> float)
```

Comment: When I get this correct, `(+)` is a function and not an operator? Also, would you consider regex to be an overkiller in this case?

Comment: @fjdumont : More to the point, `+` is a curried binary function that has infix semantics, which is what we think of as an "operator". `(+)` is merely the way to capture it for use as a function directly.

Comment: @fjdumont : And yes, personally I would consider regex to be overkill to avoid a simple `LastIndexOf` call. Which isn't to say I'm not a fan of regex in general, quite the opposite; just in *this particular case* it doesn't appear to me to add any value.